# I would like to check if someone did something, which expression should I use "did you do" or "have you done"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56513387/10731613) is discussing an OpenCV problem.

there is a guy made some comments.

I guess he did't run the code himself.

to make sure he ran the code himself and his comment is valuable.

which expression should I use "did you do" or "have you done"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is usually the case with the choice of whether to use the perfect or not, both choices are fully grammatical and fully idiomatic, and do not convey any difference in the objective events you are talking about.

The difference lies wholly in how you, as the speaker, are choosing to structure the events in time.

If you ask "Have you done it?" you are choosing to treat it as having some relevance to the present - but what that relevance is can take different forms. It might be because it is very recent. It might be because you are looking at the results of the work. It might be because you are waiting for them to complete it.

If you ask "Did you do it?" you are choosing to treat the activity as a completed action, with no particular relevance to the present. You are not excludling the possibilities I mentioned above, you are just choosing not to bring them to the foreground in your question.